# HTML Decode with encode from Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) in iPhone/iPad SDK

Tags: iphone, iso-8859-1, html-encode

I creating a rss reader for a site from Denmark, they have some thing like this in their CDATA:

```
<description><![CDATA[><p><img src="http://www.fotoagent.dk//single_picture/10851/1/small/18.Sep.2008_033_fodring_v_h_fde_40.jpg" alt="" width="150" /></p><p>For at sikre Bl&aring;vand by mod oversv&oslash;mmelse, er Kystdirektoratets strategi, at fastholde kysten mellem h&oslash;fde 1 og 6 ved at foretage strandfodringer med sand.<br /><br />Efter udbud har Rohde Nielsen A/S vundet entreprisen med at strandfodre ved Bl&aring;vand i 2010. <br /><br /><br />Der vil blive fodret med 110.</p>]]></description>
```

Please help me decode Danish text - For at sikre Blåvand by mod oversvømmelse - to NSString in unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this with MS Excel and Latin-1 codes table from W3c

```
- (NSString *)replaceHtmlEntities:(NSString *)htmlCode {

    NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:htmlCode];

    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@" " options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];

    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Agrave;" withString:@"À" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Aacute;" withString:@"Á" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Acirc;" withString:@"Â" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Atilde;" withString:@"Ã" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Auml;" withString:@"Ä" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Aring;" withString:@"Å" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&AElig;" withString:@"Æ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Ccedil;" withString:@"Ç" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Egrave;" withString:@"È" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Eacute;" withString:@"É" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Ecirc;" withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Euml;" withString:@"Ë" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Igrave;" withString:@"Ì" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Iacute;" withString:@"Í" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Icirc;" withString:@"Î" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Iuml;" withString:@"Ï" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&ETH;" withString:@"Ð" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Ntilde;" withString:@"Ñ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Ograve;" withString:@"Ò" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Oacute;" withString:@"Ó" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Ocirc;" withString:@"Ô" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Otilde;" withString:@"Õ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Ouml;" withString:@"Ö" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Oslash;" withString:@"Ø" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Ugrave;" withString:@"Ù" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Uacute;" withString:@"Ú" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Ucirc;" withString:@"Û" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Uuml;" withString:@"Ü" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Yacute;" withString:@"Ý" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&THORN;" withString:@"Þ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&szlig;" withString:@"ß" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&agrave;" withString:@"à" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&aacute;" withString:@"á" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&acirc;" withString:@"â" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&atilde;" withString:@"ã" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&auml;" withString:@"ä" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&aring;" withString:@"å" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&aelig;" withString:@"æ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&ccedil;" withString:@"ç" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&egrave;" withString:@"è" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&eacute;" withString:@"é" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&ecirc;" withString:@"ê" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&euml;" withString:@"ë" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&igrave;" withString:@"ì" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&iacute;" withString:@"í" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&icirc;" withString:@"î" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&iuml;" withString:@"ï" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&eth;" withString:@"ð" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&ntilde;" withString:@"ñ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&ograve;" withString:@"ò" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&oacute;" withString:@"ó" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&ocirc;" withString:@"ô" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&otilde;" withString:@"õ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&ouml;" withString:@"ö" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&oslash;" withString:@"ø" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&ugrave;" withString:@"ù" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&uacute;" withString:@"ú" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&ucirc;" withString:@"û" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&uuml;" withString:@"ü" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&yacute;" withString:@"ý" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&thorn;" withString:@"þ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&yuml;" withString:@"ÿ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];


    return [NSString stringWithString:temp];

}
```